# Multiple models in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Is it possible to pass multiple models into the `UpdateView`?

Something like:

```
models = (FirstModel, SecondModel)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not via the `models` attribute for `UpdateView`.

But what you can do is either utilize `extra_context` or override the `get_context_data()` and add the models there.

An example of one such override would be:

```
class TaffyUpdateView(UpdateView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TaffyUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['second_model'] = SecondModel.objects.get(id=1) #whatever you would like
        return context
```

Comment: I need to update those two models, not just pass them to the template.

Comment: Of course this was the minimal example on how you'd do it. Create a form and add it via `get_context_data()` and have it sent back.

Comment: @dimazubrik don't ask / expect tailored solutions, we won't take the fun out of it for you :) what Limelight suggested is actually a viable approach worth investigating, been doing this for the last 6 months or so at work :)